# SQL*Plus Custom Summary Report

Tags: oracle, report, sqlplus, spool

I have a requirement to generate the following summary report that look like the following:

[image]

My problem is that,

1. I have no idea on how do I fill the count data in this custom report.
2. I do not know how to put it in a table view like the above in a text document. It is not HTML.

So far, I only know how to do the first row, and column without the table view.

Here are my codes.

```
SET HEADING OFF;
SET LINESIZE 200;
SET SPACE 0; 
SET ECHO OFF;
SET FEEDBACK OFF;
SET VERIFY OFF;
SET MARKUP HTML OFF SPOOL OFF;
SET TERMOUT OFF; --Do not show output to the screen.
SET NEWPAGE NONE; --Remove the first blank line at the top of the page and between queries.

TTITLE LEFT "REPORT NAME" RIGHT "PAGE : " SQL.PNO SKIP 1 -
LEFT        "--------------------------------" RIGHT "DATE : " _DATE SKIP 1 -
LEFT "A) TOTAL RECORDS " RIGHT total_records; -- Cannot output variable in the title.
LEFT "B) MATCHED RECORDS " RIGHT matched_records; -- Cannot output variable in the title.
LEFT "C) UNMATCHED RECORDS " RIGHT matched_records; -- Cannot output variable in the title.
BTITLE LEFT "E N D";
```

total_records is an insert into statement.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO total_records FROM TABLE;
```

I have not done matched records and unmatched records. But the only way I can think of

1. Select a statement into a cursor.
2. Loop into the cursor.
3. Increase matched count when there is a match.
4. Once loop finish. unmatched count = total count - matched count.

I don't think this is the most efficient way. But, if you have a better way, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does something like this ring a bell? Example is based on Scott's sample schema:

```
SQL> select 'Total records' name, count(*) cnt
  2    from emp
  3  union all
  4  select 'Matched count', sum(case when deptno = 10 then 1 else 0 end)
  5    from emp
  6  union all
  7  select 'Unmatched count', sum(case when deptno = 10 then 0 else 1 end)
  8    from emp;

NAME                   CNT
--------------- ----------
Total records           14
Matched count            3
Unmatched count         11

SQL>
```

Comment: OHHH!! WOW!! YES!! Then I just need to adjust the column spaces accordingly. But how about the table view? Is it possible?

Comment: VIew? Yes, if query I posted suits your needs, then `create view some_view as select <copy query I posted above here>`

Comment: I am not referring to the DB view. I am referring to this spooled output text file, in table like view like the screenshot above.

Comment: Aha. Huh, probably. I don't know, last time I created "reports" using SQL*Plus was a long time ago. Nowadays I use GUI (Reports Builder).